# Hibernate Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am becoming really confused with the issues I am confronting.

I am getting this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [cities_addresses]

Here is the code to my class Address:

```
package com.bestinsurance.api.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID addressId;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String address;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String postalCode;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Address address = (Address) o;

        return Objects.equals(addressId, address.addressId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return addressId != null ? addressId.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    public UUID getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

The code to my class City

```
package com.bestinsurance.api.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID cityId;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private int population;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addresses;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        City city = (City) o;

        return Objects.equals(cityId, city.cityId);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return cityId != null ? cityId.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    public UUID getCityId() {
        return cityId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public State getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

The Schema I am working with:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset aslan:001-changeset1.sql splitStatements:false
CREATE TABLE Countries
(
    country_id uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(64)      NOT NULL,
    population int
);

CREATE TABLE States
(
    state_id   uuid PRIMARY KEY                       NOT NULL,
    country_id uuid REFERENCES Countries (country_id) NOT NULL,
    name       VARCHAR(64)                            NOT NULL,
    population int
);

CREATE TABLE Cities
(
    city_id    uuid PRIMARY KEY                       NOT NULL,
    country_id uuid REFERENCES Countries (country_id) NOT NULL,
    state_id   uuid REFERENCES States (state_id),
    name       VARCHAR(64)                            NOT NULL,
    population int

);

CREATE TABLE Addresses
(
    address_id  uuid PRIMARY KEY                       NOT NULL,
    country_id  uuid REFERENCES Countries (country_id) NOT NULL,
    city_id     uuid REFERENCES Cities (city_id)       NOT NULL,
    state_id    uuid REFERENCES States (state_id)      NOT NULL,
    address     VARCHAR(128)                           NOT NULL,
    postal_code VARCHAR(16)
);

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    customer uuid PRIMARY KEY         NOT NULL,
    name     VARCHAR(64)              NOT NULL,
    surname  VARCHAR(64)              NOT NULL,
    email    VARCHAR(320)             NOT NULL,
    created  timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated  timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    address  uuid REFERENCES Addresses (address_id) UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE Coverages
(
    coverage_id uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(16)      NOT NULL,
    description TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Policies
(
    policy_id   uuid PRIMARY KEY         NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(16)              NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    price       NUMERIC(4, 2)            NOT NULL,
    created     timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated     timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Policies_Coverages
(
    coverage_id uuid REFERENCES Coverages (coverage_id) NOT NULL,
    policy_id   uuid REFERENCES Policies (policy_id)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Subscriptions
(
    policy_id   uuid REFERENCES Policies (policy_id) NOT NULL,
    customer_id uuid REFERENCES Customers (customer) NOT NULL,
    start_date  date                                 NOT NULL,
    end_date    date                                 NOT NULL,
    paid_price  numeric(4, 2)                        NOT NULL,
    created     timestamp with time zone             NOT NULL,
    updated     timestamp with time zone             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (policy_id, customer_id)
);
```

And my application.properties file that is in the test folder since I am using testcontainers

```
# application.properties for PostgreSQL
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:14.5-alpine:///
spring.datasource.username=test-pg
spring.datasource.password=test-pg

# Disable feature detection by this undocumented parameter. Check the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServiceImpl.configure method for more details.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

# Because detection is disabled you have to set correct dialect by hand.
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
# IF YOU ARE USING SPRING 3.1.X JUST COMMENT THE PREVIOUS AND UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
# IF YOU ARE USING SPRING 3.1.X JUST COMMENT THE PREVIOUS AND UNCOMMENT THE FOLLOWING
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

#This is expected from the status rest service
api.version=1.0
```

Can anyone explain where exactly is my mistake that is triggering this issue.

Before getting this error the @JoinColumn(name = "city_id") was in city class and looked like this:

```
 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

Which was mapping the one-to-many relationship between address and city. But was getting error that looked like this

> EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [city_city_id] in table [addresses]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the City entity you should add `mapped by` like this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
    private List<Address> addresses;
```

Based on: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many